# Taking data from 3 different files and printing it as output in C language?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

Hi guys I'm currently running into an issue with a project. Basically the objective is to read the necessary info within three different files and printing the info gathered as output. The problem I'm running into right now is my conditional if statements are not doing what they're supposed to. I'm watching the values of my variables through the 'watch' feature but whenever the condition is not met (lake_x value != prv_x value) the loop still ignores it and continues through the if statement instead of jumping into the else statement.
Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int
main (void)

{
FILE *data_File;
FILE *lake_File;
FILE *beach_File;

char fileName[10], lake_Table[15],beach_Table[15];  /*.txt file names */

int lake_data=0,lake_x=0, beach_x=0, nr_tests=0;    /* variables for the file july08.txt */
int province_data=0,prv_x=0;        /* variables for the file Lake Table.txt */
int beach_data=0,bch_x=0;           /* variables for the file Beach Table.txt*/

char province[30] = ""; /*variable for the data within the file Lake Table.txt*/
char beach[20]="";   /*variable for the data within the file Beach Table.txt*/

int j;
double status, ecoli_lvl;
printf ("Which month would you like a summary of? \nType month followed by date (i.e: july05): ");
gets(fileName);

/*Opening the files needed for the program*/
data_File = fopen (fileName, "r");
lake_File = fopen ("Lake Table.txt", "r");
beach_File = fopen ("Beach Table.txt", "r");

/*Printing Headers*/
printf ("\nLake     Beach    Average     E-Coli Level        Recommendation\n"); 


/* july08.txt file*/
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &lake_x);
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &beach_x);
lake_data = fscanf (data_File, "%d", &nr_tests);

/* Lake Table.txt file*/
province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
fgets (province,30,lake_File);

/* Beach Table.txt file*/
beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
fgets (beach,20,beach_File);

status = (double) 0;

/*If the value from the july08.txt matches to value from Lake Table.txt file then print the province that matches to it in the Lake Table.txt*/!
while (province_data > 0)
{
    if (lake_x = prv_x)
    {
        printf ("%s", province);
        province_data = 0;

    }    
    else
    {
        province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
        fgets (province,30,lake_File);
    }      

}    

while (beach_data > 0)
{
    if (beach_x = bch_x)
    {
        printf ("        %s", beach);
        beach_data = 0;
    }    
    else
    {
        beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
        fgets (beach,30,beach_File);
    }

}
```

My issue starts at this point. As you can see from the image you'll notice the beach_x = 101 and bch_x = 100 but as soon as the code moves past the while statement the data becomes the same and the if statement is true and keeps on printing all the data within the Lake Table.txt file. Here's a result of what I just mentioned.

So why doesn't my if statement function properly?

```
while (lake_data != EOF)
{
    for (j=1; j<=nr_tests; ++j)
    {
        fscanf (data_File, "%lf", &ecoli_lvl);
        status = status + ecoli_lvl;
    }
    printf ("                     %.d", j);
    fscanf (data_File, "\n%d", &lake_x);
    fscanf (data_File, "%d", &beach_x);
    lake_data = fscanf (data_File, "\n%d", &nr_tests);
    printf ("\n");
}


fclose (data_File);

return (0);

}
```

Thanks a lot. Apologies for the length I'm just posting the whole code in case you needed a full picture.

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons, not `=`.  `if (beach_x == bch_x)`

Comment: Just to be clear, did you actually mean to assign within the `if` statement?  If not, then that is a major part of why your code is not working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you're absolutely right man. I just looked over my code with my bro and he noticed the same thing. I changed it and it's working now. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you are trying to compare *beach_x* and *bch_x* in the if-statement. The problem is that you are assigning the value of *bch_x* to *beach_x*.

To compare them, and to compare this result with the file, you need to do this:

```
if ((beach_x == bch_x) && (beach_x != 0)
{
    printf ("        %s", beach);
    beach_data = 0;
}    
else
{
    beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
    fgets (beach,30,beach_File);
}
```

*note*:

You can compare the file to either of the variables, since they need to be equal in the first step.

Comment: @EnxhK or even if it was your brother, this answer is still correct!

Comment: I'm still learning how to use this site. thanks for letting me know about the mark thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` for comparison, not `=`.

`if (beach_x == bch_x)`

By using `=`, all you're doing is assigning `bch_x` to `beach_x`.

You make the same error in several other `if` statements, such as this one:

```
if (lake_x = prv_x)
```